# DateTime::Event::Cron::Quartz does not handle */2 hour

Tags: perl, cron

I am trying to find next run time using [DateTime::Event::Cron::Quartz](http://search.cpan.org/~vad/DateTime-Event-Cron-Quartz-0.05/lib/DateTime/Event/Cron/Quartz.pm) module in perl. In shell `*/2` value in place of hour field means `in every 2 hour`. But same is not working in perl. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the examples.  I think you need the `0/2` syntax instead.  It says very clearly that it is not compatible with unix cron in the Bugs and Limitations section.

Comment: @xxfelixxx I tried that, but it didn't seem to work properly either. I tried to get the `0/n 30 * * *` with `n` as `2`, `3`, `4` and `5` at 9:20 but it kept giving me `9:30` as the next one. The code was too convoluted to quickly grasp, so I stopped after reading it for a minute. It might not be implemented for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found the solution. I was putting * in place of minute. Changing it to 0 solved the problem.